Не работает код, но ошибок в нём нет
Крч я писал код в python с библиотекой telebot и базой данных SQlite 3. После того как я написал строчку кода для получения номера телефон человека, у меня перестала работать другая часть кода, которая к текущему коду который я писал никак не связана. После выполнения этой ветки def send_faq_page_one(chat_id): появляеться кнопка "следущая страница", но когда я на неё нажимаю ничего не происходит. Хотя у меня всё написано что должно быть
import telebot
import sqlite3
from telebot import types

db_path = "Mydatabase.db"

# Подключение к базе данных SQLite
conn = sqlite3.connect('db_path', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Создание таблицы пользователей
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    telegram_id INTEGER UNIQUE,
                    phone_number TEXT
                )''')
conn.commit()

bot = telebot.TeleBot('***')

# Функция для добавления нового пользователя в базу данных
def add_user(telegram_id, phone_number):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (telegram_id, phone_number) VALUES (?, ?)',
                   (telegram_id, phone_number))
    conn.commit()



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    # Проверяем наличие пользователя в базе данных
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE telegram_id=?', (message.from_user.id,))
    user = cursor.fetchone()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вас вітає телеграм бот")

    if user is None:
        # Если пользователь отсутствует в базе данных, запрашиваем номер телефона
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
        btn = types.KeyboardButton(text="Надати контакт для реєстрації", request_contact=True)
        markup.add(btn)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Перед початком користуванням ботом, пропонуємо заєреструватися.")
    else:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Вартість систем")
        item6 = types.KeyboardButton("Часті питання")

        markup.add(item5, item6)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Зробіть свій вибір".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                         reply_markup=markup)

# Обработчик получения контакта
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def handle_contact(message):
    # Добавляем нового пользователя в базу данных
    add_user(message.from_user.id, message.contact.phone_number)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вартість")
    item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Часті питання")

    markup.add(item11, item10)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Дякуємо за реєстрацію.", reply_markup=markup)

def send_faq_page_three(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Вартість")
    item6 = types.KeyboardButton("Часті питання")

    markup.add(item5, item6)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Зробіть свій вибір".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Вартість':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тут будуть вартості")
        elif message.text == 'Часті питання':
            send_faq_page_one(message.chat.id)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не правильна комбінація')


def send_faq_page_one(chat_id):
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Ось часті питання які нам задають та їх відповіді',
                     reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Наступна сторінка", callback_data='Next page')
    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(chat_id, '1. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '2. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '3. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '4. ...\n Відповідь:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'Next page':
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                      text='*Видаленно*', reply_markup=None)
                send_faq_page_two(call.message.chat.id)
            elif call.data == 'Start over':
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                      text='*Видаленно*', reply_markup=None)
                send_faq_page_one(call.message.chat.id)
            elif call.data == 'Main':
                bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                      text='*Видаленно*', reply_markup=None)
                send_faq_page_three(call.message)
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


def send_faq_page_two(chat_id):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Почати спочатку", callback_data='Start over')
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Меню", callback_data='Main')
    markup.add(item2, item3)

    bot.send_message(chat_id, '5. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '6. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '7. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '8. ...\n Відповідь:', replay_markup=markup)


# RUN
bot.polling()```


Что именно не работает? Пытались ли вы обнаружить ошибку или как-то логировать события?
Чуть-чуть подправил код и заработало. Сообщите, та ли эта ошибка, с который вы столкнулись?
Я нашёл только одну ошибку, которая происходила в функции send_faq_page_two().
TypeError("TeleBot.send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replay_markup'")
Ошибка, говорит, что вы допустили опечатку в названии аргумента вы написали replay_markup, а правильно reply_markup.
Ещё одна ошибка возникала из-за того, что вы должны указывать callback_data
types.InlineKeyboardButton('some text', callback_data='some_callback')

import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3


bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

db_path = "Mydatabase.db"

# Подключение к базе данных SQLite
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path, check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Создание таблицы пользователей
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    telegram_id INTEGER UNIQUE,
                    phone_number TEXT
                )''')
conn.commit()


# Функция для добавления нового пользователя в базу данных
def add_user(telegram_id, phone_number):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (telegram_id, phone_number) VALUES (?, ?)',
                   (telegram_id, phone_number))
    conn.commit()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    # Проверяем наличие пользователя в базе данных
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE telegram_id=?', (message.from_user.id,))
    user = cursor.fetchone()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вас вітає телеграм бот")

    if user is None:
        # Если пользователь отсутствует в базе данных, запрашиваем номер телефона
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
        btn = types.KeyboardButton(text="Надати контакт для реєстрації", request_contact=True)
        markup.add(btn)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Перед початком користуванням ботом, пропонуємо заєреструватися.",
                         reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Вартість систем")
        item6 = types.KeyboardButton("Часті питання")

        markup.add(item5, item6)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Зробіть свій вибір".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                         reply_markup=markup)


# Обработчик получения контакта
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def handle_contact(message):
    # Добавляем нового пользователя в базу данных
    add_user(message.from_user.id, message.contact.phone_number)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вартість", callback_data='data')
    item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Часті питання", callback_data='callback_data')

    markup.add(item11, item10)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Дякуємо за реєстрацію.", reply_markup=markup)


def send_faq_page_three(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Вартість")
    item6 = types.KeyboardButton("Часті питання")

    markup.add(item5, item6)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Зробіть свій вибір".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Вартість':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тут будуть вартості")
        elif message.text == 'Часті питання':
            send_faq_page_one(message.chat.id)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не правильна комбінація')


def send_faq_page_one(chat_id):
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Ось часті питання які нам задають та їх відповіді',
                     reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Наступна сторінка", callback_data='Next page')
    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(chat_id, '1. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '2. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '3. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '4. ...\n Відповідь:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'Next page':
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                      text='*Видаленно*', reply_markup=None)
                send_faq_page_two(call.message.chat.id)
            elif call.data == 'Start over':
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                      text='*Видаленно*', reply_markup=None)
                send_faq_page_one(call.message.chat.id)
            elif call.data == 'Main':
                bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                      text='*Видаленно*', reply_markup=None)
                send_faq_page_three(call.message)
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


def send_faq_page_two(chat_id):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Почати спочатку", callback_data='Start over')
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Меню", callback_data='Main')
    markup.add(item2, item3)

    bot.send_message(chat_id, '5. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '6. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '7. ...\n Відповідь:\n'
                              '8. ...\n Відповідь:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


# RUN
bot.polling()


Я тебе безгранично благодарен, за то что исправил некоторые ошибки о которых я не подозревал, но к сожалению основная проблема не исчезла, чтобы ты понял что у меня не работает я прикреплю ссылку на фотографию [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NGuO8a_tCHND8zP8Q00TPd9aijFfABlX/view?usp=sharing].

А также я нашёл другую ошибку, если можешь помочь, помоги пожалуйста. У меня после того как я активировал код в первые и отправил боту свой номер, у меня крашнулся скрипт. Вот ссылка на ошибку [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRJyuhFnU51hb2E1sBbMU_825a3x-6Ez/view?usp=sharing]. А вот что мне сказал ChatGPT Ошибка заключается в том, что используется текстовая кнопка во встроенной клавиатуре чата, что не разрешено в соответствии с API Telegram. Таким образом, нужно просмотреть код и убедиться, что все кнопки, которые добавляются к клавиатуре, являются кнопками inline, а не текстовыми.

Проверьте теперь.

А что у вас не работает в этой части, при нажатии на кнопку как у вас на скриншоте код продолжает работу.
https://i.imgur.com/SLm9Pa4.jpeg

Это скорее всего проблемы у меня по этому всё норм

Отметьте тогда моё сообщение, как решение, если оно действительно помогло вам.
